# light clock mirrors

Tags: special-relativity

Are the mirrors in a light clock the same perpendicular distance apart in the moving and stationary frames? Note this is not a question about the  different distance the light travels in different frames.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#/media/File:Time_dilation02.gif

Answer (score 1):

Yes,mirrors will be at same distance from each other in both frames.
Lorentz contraction happens only in the direction of motion,not perpendicular to it.[image]